# A* - Simple graph example - wrong result

Tags: algorithm, a-star

I’ve implemented and used A* several times and thought I knew everything there was to know about A*…. Until I encountered this example:

[image: A* directed graph example]

The graph consists of 4 nodes and 6 directed weighted edges. The heuristic is denoted per node by `H=…`. The heuristic is clearly admissible, so I don't see any problems with that.

The problem is to find the route from *start* to *goal* with the minimal total cost. The correct solution is the route taking the edges with the costs 36 and 18.

My implementation of A* performs the following steps(omitting any operations related to the closed list):

- The startnode is {G = 0, H = 200, -> F = 200} and is selected as ‘current node’
- All its neighbours are added to the openlist `= {{G=5, H=100, F=105}, {G=36, H=100, F=136}}`.
- The new ‘current node’ is selected, which is the node in the open list with smallest F, which is the node with `F = 105`, the upper node in the image.
- The neighbours of that node are added to the openlist, which then has the elements { {G=36, H=100,F=136}, {G=58,H=0,F=58}}.
- Again a new current node is selected, which is the goal node, so the algorithm terminates and the route with the costs 5 and 53 is selected.

So the implementation produces the wrong result. What in these steps shouldn’t have happened?

Comment: Well, this is of course not a graph (because there are pairs of nodes which share two edges instead of one or zero), but that's not the reason A* does not work here. One could easily make a graph out of this by replacing each of the double edges by the one with the lower cost.

Comment: @Doc Brown - This is of course a graph, provided you adopt the appropriate graph definition. Specifically, it is a directed multigraph without loops. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph) (which is, of course, always correct about everything :~)): "In mathematics, a multigraph or pseudograph is a graph which is permitted to have multiple edges,..."

Comment: @Ted Hopp: if you read the Wikipedia article in detail, you will find it gives different definitions for the term "graph", and a "multigraph" does not match the most common definition. Nevertheless, the question that matters here is "does A* apply to multigraphs?" and the answer is - "not directly, but by transforming the multigraph into a classical graph, it can be applied."

Comment: @Doc Brown - A* is perfectly capable of searching a multigraph. If you need to reconstruct the optimal path when the goal is reached, then you just need to keep an edge reference as well as a parent reference when a node is explored. You also need to consider all edges between two nodes instead of a single edge. But those are just implementation details, not a modification of A* (or of the multigraph).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a heuristic to be admissible, it must be bounded from *above* by the actual cost to the goal. Your heuristic is not admissible and that's why you're getting the wrong answer. See, for instance, the [Wikipedia article on A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm).

Comment: Awww, I'm ashamed of myself for mixing up bounded from _above_ and _below_. Thank you

Comment: Well, at least you've created a nice example of how A* can fail when the heuristic is not admissible. :)

Comment: Couldn't one make the heuristic admissible when 'normalizing' the distances too?

Comment: @Karussell - I don't understand the question. What do you mean by _"'normalizing' the distances"_?

Comment: Sorry, for not explaining this in detail. I mean, when you are omiting the square root you are in fact changing (normalizing) the distance calculation. To make this working you need to do this for ALL distance calculations not only for H ... so do it also for the G.

Comment: Oh, probably this does not work as one would need to "denormalize" everytime one sums distances. At least it'll be slower instead faster. Hmmh but somehow there might be a solution.

Comment: @Karussell - Squaring the distances for comparison purposes would not help unless H was somehow then a lower bound on the actual cost to the goal. Since a^2 + b^2 <= (a + b)^2, using squared distances for calculating H certainly wouldn't hurt in this regard. However ,OP's problem was that H was not a lower bound, and squaring distances wouldn't have changed that.